# Error 1 error C2664: 'arl::contFolder *arl::list::setDown(arl::contFolder *,int *)' : cannot convert argument 2 from 'unsigned int' to 'int *'

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2012, parameter-passing

I have the function

```
void file::pg_down(fldr *f)
    {
        drawItem(*f, drw::Colours::blueVivid);
        f->item_pos = myList.setDown(f->active->next, f->cord.x);
        if (!strcmp(f->item_pos->name, myStr))
            f->item_pos = f->item_pos->prev;

        drawItem(*f, drw::Colours::greenVivid);
    }
```

**that calls the function**

```
contFolder* list::setDown(contFolder* current, int *xCord)
    {
        arl::contFolder* tmp = NULL;
        arl::contFolder* i = NULL;
        for (i = current; i->next; i = i->next, xCord++)
        {
            if (!strcmp(i->name, myStr))
            {
                tmp = i;
                return tmp;
            }
        }
        tmp = i;
        return tmp;
    }
```

and I need the function  **contFolder* list::setDown(contFolder* current, int *xCord)** to change the value of **xCord**, but can't understand how to pass this argument correctly. 
Therefore I have the error

> Error 1 error C2664: 'arl::contFolder
>   *arl::list::setDown(arl::contFolder *,int *)' : cannot convert argument 2 from 'unsigned int' to 'int *'

What would you reccomend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myList.setDown(f->active->next, f->cord.x);
```

Should be

```
myList.setDown(f->active->next, (int*)&f->cord.x);
```

Your function `setDown` takes an `int*`, not an `int`, so pass the address of your variable.

Also, you have a type mismatch.  Why does your function take an `int*` when you're storing coordinates as `unsigned int`s?  Just take the correct type...

```
contFolder* list::setDown(contFolder* current, unsigned int *xCord);
```

BTW, you never actually use `xCord`. You increment it, but it's a copy of a pointer, so it has no effect on `f->cord.x`.  What are you actually trying to do here?  If you're trying to increment `f->cord.x` then you would need to use `(*xCord)++`.

Comment: I tried that as well, though it shows the same error/

Comment: @Eugene: Oh, no, it's not the same error.  I just realized that `f->coord.x` is an *unsigned* int, not an int. You have a type mismatch. You'll have to cast.

Comment: SO what would you recommend to do?

Comment: @Eugene: You use a cast or change your type. Why does your function take an `int*` when you're storing coordinates as `unsigned int`s?

Comment: Error 1 error C2664: 'arl::contFolder *arl::list::setDown(arl::contFolder *,int *)' : cannot convert argument 2 from 'unsigned int *' to 'int *'

Comment: thank you, it worked fine with new type unsigned int...Have a good day.

Comment: @Eugene: Well, it's not really working yet though (even if it compiles).  Look at my last edit.